# tasks run in thread takes longer than in serial?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, pthreads

So im doing some computation on 4 million nodes.

the very bask serial version just have a for loop which loops 4 million times and do 4 million times of computation. this takes roughly 1.2 sec.

when I split the for loop to, say, 4 for loops and each does 1/4 of the computation, the total time became 1.9 sec.

I guess there are some overhead in creating for loops and maybe has to do with cpu likes to compute data in chunk.

The real thing bothers me is when I try to put 4 loops to 4 thread on a 8 core machine, each thread would take 0.9 seconds to finish. 
I am expecting each of them to only take 1.9/4 second instead.

I dont think there are any race condition or synchronize issue since all I do was having a for loop to create 4 threads, which took 200 microseconds. And then a for loop to joins them.

The computation read from a shared array and write to a different shared array.
I am sure they are not writing to the same byte.

Where could the overhead came from?

main: ncores: number of cores.  node_size: size of graph (4 million node)

```
        for(i = 0 ; i < ncores ; i++){
            int *t = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
            *t = i;
            int iret = pthread_create( &thread[i], NULL, calculate_rank_p, (void*)(t));

        }
        for (i = 0; i < ncores; i++)
        {
            pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
        }
```

calculate_rank_p: vector is the rank vector for page rank calculation

```
Void *calculate_rank_pthread(void *argument) {
    int index = *(int*)argument;
    for(i = index; i < node_size ; i+=ncores)     
       current_vector[i] = calc_r(i, vector);
    return NULL;     
}
```

calc_r: this is just a page rank calculation using compressed row format.

```
double calc_r(int i, double *vector){
    double prank = 0;
    int j;
    for(j = row_ptr[i]; j < row_ptr[i+1]; j++){
        prank += vector[col_ind[j]] * val[j];
    }
    return prank;
}
```

everything that is not declared are global variable

Comment: Post the code, so we can see where the issue might be.

Comment: Solving this issue takes longer than is some of the code was posted.  So by posting all at once (in parallel) the code, input and expected out needed), this can be advanced quickly rather than serially asking for various information.

Comment: Ohwait.. what, exactly, is 'for(i = index; i < node_size ; i+=ncores)' doing?   I mean, it looks to me like each thread is operating on ints that are 'ncores' apart.  How far apert is that, and what is your cache line size??

Comment: You should give each thread a contiguous chunk of ints to work on, 'i++', NOT 'i+=ncores'.

Comment: ncores is the number of cores(thread). in my case, 4.

Comment: ^^ you're stuft on false cache sharing:(

Comment: I did that before. But my data does does not distribute evenly so that there are more work to do in the begin and very less in the end.  So if im dividing it to 16 even piece, the first 1 would take 0.8 sec while the last one would take 0.1 sec.

Comment: Yeah... this is one reason why shoving tasks onto pools is better than all that thread micro-management.

Comment: can you explain a bit furthuer? I just looked up what thread pool is and I'm not sure if I get the idea. It seems like thread pool is used to avoid thread_create overhead since you don't close them but put them to idle when finished and signal them to do next round of work then. But I still need to specify which part of data they need to calculate right?

Comment: Yeah, but you could split up the tasks into, say, 64 chunks and submit those.   That would spread the load better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The computation read from a shared array and write to a different shared array. I am sure they are not writing to the same byte.

It's impossible to be sure without seeing relevant code and having some more details, but this sounds like it could be due to false sharing, or ...

> the performance issue of false sharing (aka cache line ping-ponging), where threads use different objects but those objects happen to be close enough in memory that they fall on the same cache line, and the cache system treats them as a single lump that is effectively protected by a hardware write lock that only one core can hold at a time. This causes real but invisible performance contention; whichever thread currently has exclusive ownership so that it can physically perform an update to the cache line will silently throttle other threads that are trying to use different (but, alas, nearby) data that sits on the same line.

http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/eliminate-false-sharing/217500206

**UPDATE**

This looks like it could very well trigger false sharing, depending on the size of a vector (though there is still not enough information in the post to be sure, as we don't see how the various `vector` are allocated.

```
for(i = index; i < node_size ; i+=ncores)
```

Instead of interleaving which core works on which data `i += ncores` give each of them a range of data to work on.

Comment: To avoid this, should I store the thread's result in seperate arrays and then brings them together after they finish?

Comment: They don't necessarily have to be separate arrays, but the threads need to work on regions of memory that are sufficiently separated so that they don't contend for the same cache lines.  The linked article gives some really good advice.  It certainly would resolve the issue, though, if this is your issue, by using one array per thread since that forces each thread to have its own address range.

Comment: So I just tried to create a local variable in each thread and save the computation result there. However, the computation time for each thread did not improve.  I am only calculating the computation time using gettimeofday.

Comment: Yeah - this looks so false-sharing that it should be jailed for contempt, or maybe fraud:)

Comment: @LoveProgramming: See update.  There is a candidate for triggering false sharing in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

For me the same surprise when build and run in Debug (other test code though).

In release all as expected ;)

Comment: Your answer should be a comment instead as it's not giving directly useful "answer" to the question.